# How to make plotly scatterplot axes uniformly spaced?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I need to make a simple scatterplot in plotly but am facing some formatting issues. Here's the code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[54,44,43,43,63,55,59],'y':[1259305,1295003,1888391,2000000,1500001,1123433,1459330]})

fig = px.scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [0, 50, 100]
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [df['y'].min(),df['y'].median(),df['y'].max()]))
fig.show()
```

This is what it's displaying:

[image]

I need the axes and gridlines to be uniformly spaced according to the specifications I provided for xaxis and yaxis and not automatically adjust based on the distribution of values in the data.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks so much.

EDIT: I would like to replicate this matplotlib graph in plotly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To specify individually, please see the following [reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/main/README.md#locale_format) for detailed settings. My guess is that you want to display it as normal, so I will answer.

```
fig = px.scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [0, 50, 100]
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [df['y'].min(),df['y'].median(),df['y'].max()]),
    yaxis_tickformat=' ')
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
yaxis_tickformat='g'
```

[image]

```
x xais tick customize

    xaxis = dict(
        range=[0,100], # update
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = [0, 50, 100],
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to display it with a comma, you can do it like this. `yaxis_tickformat=','` If my answer helps you, please click the check mark to accept and insert your answer.

Comment: But you see how the boxes are so uneven? Why is that? I want it so all the squares are equal size and that all 3 ticks are displayed on the x axis too.

Comment: You are specifying the minimum, median, and maximum values for the y-axis, so the median is not always the middle. You can replace it with the average value.

Comment: When I use the same code in matplotlib I get the result I'm looking for. I'm going to add it to the screenshots above. Can you show me how to reproduce this in plotly?

Comment: code and graph updated

Comment: but why does the x axis only display 50, not 0, 50 and 100

Comment: The tick marks on the x-axis are specified by specifying the data range in list form.